# How to observe managed object context

Tags: iphone, notifications, nsfetchedresultscontroller, key-value-observing

Whenever i make a change in the objects in the first tab of my application the updates are automatically upated in tab 2 becuase it uses a fetchedResultsController. Now i have a third tab that should also update itself, but how can i do that?

I only have a nsmangedObjectContext in the third tab to get the appropriate data. How can i receive notifications whenever the objects in this context change?

I am also struggeling with the question how i can make my data fetching more efficient, becuase tab 2 and 3 use the same set of data. I am currently making another fetch in tab 3, to get the same data as tab 2. I dont know how i can use the data from tab2 without disturbing the fetchedresultscontroller.

Information on this subject would really be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your tableviews are very closely related, then you can just have a single `UITableViewDataSource` that provides data for both of them, and have it manage the `NSFetchedResultsController`. From your description, this case seems very likely.

If the tableviews are not very similar, such that having a single `UITableViewDataSource` would create excessive `if()` logic, then move your `NSFetchedResultsController` into an separate model object and post `NSNotifications` when it receives delegate call-backs. Your `UITableViewDataSources` can then observe those notifications to update themselves when they are on-screen.

Comment: Thanks for your information! But my third tab is not a table view. So i am dealing with a tableview(tab 2) and a regular view(tab 3). What should i do then..

Comment: In that case the latter solution above is likely easier to understand if you do not have a strong background in designing MVC. If I were doing it, I would probably make a single data object that was a datasource for both views, but that requires designing a datasource protocol for your second view and separating the tableview controller from the tableview datasource. Those aren't hard, but even so I might recommend going with my second design above since it is closer to Apple sample code.